# Access a single object from Database ListView using Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I have a class that passes in a django `ListView`. From this `ListView` I can access my DB items. My problem is that accessing the db using the list view will load all the entries. what if I just want one entry, say the 5th entry for example. Maybe `listView` is the wrong type of view to be using? my code below work and shows my DB entries on-screen as a list.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Datadata(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
```

**views.py**

```
class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Datadata
    template_name = 'hello.html'
```

**templates/hello.html**

```
{% for post in object_list %}
<h1>{{ post.text }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Then you normally use a `DetailView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you normally use a [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview). You can for example define this as:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class HomePageView(DetailView):
    model = Datadata
    template_name = 'hello.html'
```

You can then render this for example with:

```
<h1>{{ object.text }}</h1>
```

What is convenient is that a `DetailView`, just like all views with a [**`SingleObjectModelMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin) autoamtically filter on the primary key `pk` or slug field.

So the url pattern should look like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('data/<int:pk>/', HomePageView.as_view(), name='data-detail'),
]
```

If we then access `/data/5` for example, it will show the data for the item with as primary key `5`.

Comment: Thank you this is very good. However, what i am trying to do is more be able to select different elements in the data base, and place them around my html. For example if i want the first entry of my DB to be located in my HTML banner, then the 2nd element to be placed in `<H1>` tags, and the 3rd element to be in `<p>` tags. so would it be more like accessing these element by `{{ object.text[:1] }}` or something like that?  So i just want my `url path` to point to my `hello/` and then be able to populate my `HTML` with my DB elements. if that makes sense.